# What PHP Needed to Make One Loop with Multiple Styling?

Tags: loop

I understand that there is a way to have the loop display multiple ways on one page without using multiple loops... Or in other words something like:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : ?>
<!-- Code for the First Post -->
<?php else: ?>
<!-- Code for Posts 2-4 -->
<?php else: ?>
<!-- Code for Posts 5-12 -->
<!-- stuff to close loop -->
```

Problem is that I don't really know php well, and I have no idea how to have it count posts and how to tell it for the first post do X, for posts 2 through 4 do X, and for posts 5 through 12 do X... If anyone can point me to a clear tutorial or let me know what PHP is necessary, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should read about `if/else/while/for/foreach` on http://php.net first. This surely helps you getting 90% of your Qs out of your way in less than 20 minutes.

Comment: I understand how if/else statements themselves work, it's just I don't understand how telling Wordpress to count and for x# of posts works...

Answer (score 2):

this is your answer... however like Kaiser said, you should really take some time to read a little...

```
 <?php 
 $i=0;  
 if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
      if($i==0) { ?>

         // YOUR FIRST POST CONTENT

      } else if(($i==1) || ($i==2) || ($i==3)) {

         // POST 2, 3, 4

      } else {

         // everything else

      }
 $i++;
 endwhile;
```

This is a fast answer and is not the ideal approach, but it will solve your problem...

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. I've been trying to read but I'm having difficulty understanding how counting works... And php.net isn't exactly easy to understand.

Comment: if the answer worked for you, please remember to mark it, so other people will be able to find a solution for similar problems